# lapply instead of for loop

Tags: r, lapply

I have the following huge dataframe :

```
V1  V2  V3  V4
A   E   R   12
A   R   T   18
A   T   Y   44
A   Y   U   11
B   E   R   22
B   R   T   53
B   T   Y   11
B   Y   U   153
```

what im trying to do is to get the outlier value from `V4` for each pair of `(V1,V2)`

This easily handled with 2 for loops based on the unique values of `V1` and `V2` and a `subset` for each round, take the vector of V4 for each subset and get the outlier using any function of the `outlier` package, but the the problem is then speed.

i have never used `lapply`, maybe someone can guide me on a way to perform this efficiently using `lapply` insted of the for loop.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but perhaps something like `lapply(split(DF$V4, do.call(paste, DF[c("V1", "V2")])), my_outlier_fun)` helps?.

Comment: What is your parameter for an outlier in this data set?

Comment: Assuming you mean the `outliers` (not `outlier`) package.

Comment: @RichardScriven im just using this function : `chisq.out.test(x) `from the `outlie`r package.

Comment: Btw, each pair is different in your example, so there is only one value for each pair.  Do you mean all permutations of V1, V2?

Comment: @alexis_laz : actually what you wrote works for me.
RichardScriven : you are right, but the dataframe is larger, i just gave an example of it. their should be similar pairs.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems `chisq.out.test` only tests whether a single value - the maximum (or minimum, if `opposite=TRUE`) - is an outlier. Is that what you want?

Comment: @jbaums yep this is exactly what i want, and i also want to output the row in the dataframe that gave this outlier for each pair. I managed to print the value of the outlier for each pair, but it doesnt make sense to look again in the dataframe to get the full row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

For close to 4.5 million rows, with 676 groups and 6500 records per group, it takes just over 2 seconds (including data generation).

```
library(outliers)
library(data.table)

# Fake data generation and coercion to data.table
d <- as.data.table(expand.grid(x=LETTERS, y=LETTERS, z=LETTERS))
d <- do.call(rbind, replicate(250, d, FALSE))

# > d
#          x y z      value     row
#       1: A A A -1.1712284       1
#       2: B A A  0.1818000       2
#       3: C A A -1.3959594       3
#       4: D A A -0.4778956       4
#       5: E A A -2.0426768       5
#      ---                         
# 4393996: V Z Z  0.4024398 4393996
# 4393997: W Z Z  0.9891237 4393997
# 4393998: X Z Z  1.2066572 4393998
# 4393999: Y Z Z  2.3023321 4393999
# 4394000: Z Z Z -0.8343059 4394000

# Add random "value" column and a column to keep track of row numbers
d[, c('value', 'row'):=list(rnorm(nrow(d)), seq_len(nrow(d)))]

# For each group (combination of x and y), perform the outlier test
outliers <- d[, chisq.out.test(value), list(x, y)]

# Add the row numbers for min and max numbers of each group
outliers <- merge(outliers, 
                  d[, list(min.ind=row[which.min(value)], 
                           max.ind=row[which.max(value)]), list(x, y)], 
                  by=c('x', 'y'))

# Create a new outlier column. If the p.value is >= 0.05, set outlier = NA,
# else if p.value < 0.5, then if "alternative" column contains "lowest", set
# outlier = min.ind, else max.ind.
outliers[, outlier:=ifelse(p.value < 0.05, 
                  ifelse(grepl('lowest', outliers[, alternative]), min.ind, max.ind), 
                  NA)]
```

Output looks like the following:

```
# > outliers
#      x y statistic                                  alternative      p.value                       method
#   1: A A  13.69290 highest value 3.70310786094858 is an outlier 2.152665e-04 chi-squared test for outlier
#   2: A B  11.99842 lowest value -3.47397308041372 is an outlier 5.324581e-04 chi-squared test for outlier
#   3: A C  12.41749 highest value 3.49833131757565 is an outlier 4.253310e-04 chi-squared test for outlier
#   4: A D  16.18416 lowest value -4.00696031141966 is an outlier 5.747273e-05 chi-squared test for outlier
#   5: A E  12.32196 lowest value -3.56650649267448 is an outlier 4.476613e-04 chi-squared test for outlier
#  ---                                                                                                     
# 672: Z V  11.66230 lowest value -3.43256736243089 is an outlier 6.377944e-04 chi-squared test for outlier
# 673: Z W  14.11816 highest value 3.75476979294983 is an outlier 1.716780e-04 chi-squared test for outlier
# 674: Z X  15.63605 highest value 3.93390421620766 is an outlier 7.677674e-05 chi-squared test for outlier
# 675: Z Y  17.05664 lowest value -4.12928000349912 is an outlier 3.628127e-05 chi-squared test for outlier
# 676: Z Z  14.44709 lowest value -3.82794835873449 is an outlier 1.441520e-04 chi-squared test for outlier
#      data.name min.ind max.ind outlier
#   1:     value 3609165 1191113 1191113
#   2:     value  105483 3476019  105483
#   3:     value 4153397 1375713 1375713
#   4:     value 3406443 2539135 3406443
#   5:     value   25117 2004445   25117
#  ---                                  
# 672:     value 1871740 2551796 1871740
# 673:     value 1003782 2158390 2158390
# 674:     value 1555424 1492556 1492556
# 675:     value 2071914 1344538 2071914
# 676:     value 2281500  426556 2281500
```

A bit fiddly, perhaps, but hey, it got us there in the end.